# Get files with wildcard characters

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a method that will receive path with wildcard such as:
c:\temp\aa*.xml
I want to return `List<FileInfo>`

I'm tring with

```
var directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
var filesName = Path.GetFileName(path);

IDirectoryInfoWrap directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfoWrap(directoryName);
var res = directoryInfo.GetFiles(filesName).ToList();
```

But it fails since Path.Get... doesn't work with path that contains wildcards.

I've tried splitting the path but.. `Path.LastIndexOf(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)` doesn't work by returning -1... I can split and concat but it seems like to much work for that small functionality.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
string fullFilePath = "c:\temp\aa*.xml";
string fileNamePattern = Path.GetFileName(fullFilePath);
string sourceDirectory = fullFilePath.Replace(fileNamePattern, string.Empty);

try
{
    var foundFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, fileNamePattern );

    foreach (string currentFile in foundFiles)
    {
      //Do whatever you need with the file here...
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //Handle exceptions here..
}
```

Comment: I don't know what is the sourceDirectory.. its all coming in a path parameter.. it can be also be UNC

Comment: It turns out to be diffrent prob :(.. my unit test send "c:\temp\aa*" as path and not "c:\\temp\\aa". But your code still worked :) Thanks!

Comment: BTW, The method is not testable since you are using Directory.Enum at a static ref. I guess you can break it into 2 methods one that returns IDirectoryInfoWrap and another that consumes it.